# How can I access form from another controller class in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

Class: DbUserController.cs

```
      btnTamam.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        ......
        ........
      FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
      fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/View/PerformancePage.fxml"));        
      AnchorPane frame = fxmlLoader.load();
      PerformancePageController c = (PerformancePageController) fxmlLoader.getController();
      c.txtUrl.setText("TEST TEST");
    });
```

> txtUrl = PerformancePage.fxml TextField
>   c.txtUrl.setText("TEST TEST");

The code I'm pointing to is not working.

It does not write "TEST TEST" into TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading a new pane:

```
AnchorPane frame = fxmlLoader.load();
```

But you aren't adding that pane to the displayed SceneGraph.

Comment: I understand. How can I fix?

Comment: You need to add the frame to the current scene, or place it on it's own stage.  In your code snippet there isn't enough information to be more precise that what I provided you.

Comment: Or, if you are already loading `PerformancePage.fxml` elsewhere, and *then displaying it*, you need to get the controller from the loader that loads the displayed instance. The point is you need the controller that is attached to the instance of the UI that is displayed.

Comment: You need to add that to the scene.  Is there a spot on the UI you are expecting to see this?  Without more understanding of your layout, there really isn't much I can help with.  Right now you have a node loaded into a variable. You need to attach that somehow to the UI.  i.e. root.getChildren().add(frame);